# Magento get product images in shoppping cart

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I'm trying to get all the product images of all the products in the shopping cart. I've used the following code:

```
$_item = $this->getItem();
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());

foreach ($_product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {
    echo var_export($image->getUrl());
    echo "<br>";
}
```

But this only displays all the images of the first produuct in the shopping cart. I've tried it this way:

```
foreach ($this->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {
    echo var_export($image->getUrl());
    echo "<br>";
}
```

But this doesn't return anything. How can I get all the images of all the products?

Comment: where are you trying to do this? `$this` should be a value coming from an iteration (for example a `foreach()` over the cart-items). If you could explain exactly where you want this set of images, I could help you further

Comment: I'm doing this in `default.phtml` which can be found in `checkout/cart/item`

Answer (score 0):

Use `$this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(50,50)` to retrieve the thumbnail image.

Use this example to get a different kind of image from the product:

```
$_product = $this->getItem()->getProduct();
Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(100,100);
```